MSI Cyborg 15 A12V WiFi Stopped Working
dmesg | grep iwlwifi
CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   62.389507] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   62.389510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[   62.389512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[   62.389514] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000001B8 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[   62.389523] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x8048bb7c
[   62.389525] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[   62.389528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Starting mac, retry will be triggered anyway
[   62.389634] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD UNKNOWN
[   62.389651]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   62.389677]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   62.389693]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   62.389770]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   62.390024] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to configure RX queues: -5
[   62.402518] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: mac start retry 1
[   62.413301] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   62.511958] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[   62.512007] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[   62.512015] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[   62.512024] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10
[   62.513179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 4
[   62.581624] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   62.581725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   62.581726] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
[   62.581728] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 81.31fc9ae6.0 so-a0-hr-b0-81.ucode
[   62.581730] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[   62.581731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00A082F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   62.581733] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   62.581734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D8B5C | branchlink2
[   62.581735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CEDFA | interruptlink1
[   62.581736] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CEDFA | interruptlink2
[   62.581738] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00014F1A | data1
[   62.581739] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
[   62.581740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   62.581741] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   62.581742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001D7C9 | tsf low
[   62.581743] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   62.581745] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   62.581746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028FB6 | time gp2
[   62.581747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   62.581748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | uCode version major
[   62.581749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31FC9AE6 | uCode version minor
[   62.581751] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
[   62.581752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C80002 | board version
[   62.581753] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8032FF00 | hcmd
[   62.581754] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20028000 | isr0
[   62.581755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   62.581756] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[   62.581758] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[   62.581759] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   62.581760] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   62.581761] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00014F1A | wait_event
[   62.581762] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   62.581763] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   62.581764] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   62.581766] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   62.581767] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   62.581768] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   62.581769] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000828 | flow_handler
[   62.581819] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   62.581820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
[   62.581821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20103428 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   62.581822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   62.581823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8046D5A0 | umac branchlink2
[   62.581823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081500 | umac interruptlink1
[   62.581824] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   62.581825] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000033 | umac data1
[   62.581826] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000F | umac data2
[   62.581826] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   62.581827] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | umac major
[   62.581828] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31FC9AE6 | umac minor
[   62.581828] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028FB0 | frame pointer
[   62.581829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886C1C | stack pointer
[   62.581830] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00070C01 | last host cmd
[   62.581831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   62.581876] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   62.581877] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   62.581926] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000050E1 | IML/ROM data1
[   62.581935] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   62.581942] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   62.581985] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   62.581989] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80350002 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   62.581992] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   62.581995] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   62.582038] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   62.582041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   62.582044] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   62.582046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   62.582049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   62.582053] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   62.582058] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   62.582063] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   62.582066] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   62.582068] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[   62.582071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[   62.582073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000001B8 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[   62.582082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x8048bb7c
[   62.582084] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[   62.582087] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Starting mac, retry will be triggered anyway
[   62.582141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD UNKNOWN
[   62.582159]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   62.582185]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   62.582201]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   62.582279]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   62.582515] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to configure RX queues: -5
[   62.594182] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: mac start retry 2
[   62.605483] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   62.704013] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[   62.704024] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[   62.704033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[   62.704041] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10
[   62.705267] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 4
[   62.773469] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   62.773656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   62.773657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
[   62.773658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 81.31fc9ae6.0 so-a0-hr-b0-81.ucode
[   62.773660] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[   62.773661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00A082F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   62.773662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   62.773662] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D8B5C | branchlink2
[   62.773663] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001A70 | interruptlink1
[   62.773664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001A70 | interruptlink2
[   62.773665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00014F1A | data1
[   62.773665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
[   62.773666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   62.773667] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   62.773667] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001D6D1 | tsf low
[   62.773668] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   62.773669] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   62.773670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028E5B | time gp2
[   62.773670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   62.773671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | uCode version major
[   62.773672] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31FC9AE6 | uCode version minor
[   62.773672] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
[   62.773673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C80002 | board version
[   62.773674] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8032FF00 | hcmd
[   62.773675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20020000 | isr0
[   62.773675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   62.773676] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[   62.773677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[   62.773677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   62.773678] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   62.773679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00014F1A | wait_event
[   62.773679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   62.773680] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   62.773681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   62.773681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   62.773682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   62.773683] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   62.773683] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000828 | flow_handler
[   62.773731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   62.773732] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
[   62.773733] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20103428 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   62.773734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   62.773734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8046D5A0 | umac branchlink2
[   62.773735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081500 | umac interruptlink1
[   62.773736] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   62.773736] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000033 | umac data1
[   62.773737] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000F | umac data2
[   62.773738] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   62.773738] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | umac major
[   62.773739] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31FC9AE6 | umac minor
[   62.773740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028E56 | frame pointer
[   62.773740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886C1C | stack pointer
[   62.773741] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00070C01 | last host cmd
[   62.773742] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   62.773781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   62.773782] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   62.773790] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000507D | IML/ROM data1
[   62.773798] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   62.773803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   62.773806] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   62.773808] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80350002 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   62.773811] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   62.773813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   62.773816] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   62.773818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   62.773821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   62.773823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   62.773826] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   62.773831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   62.773835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   62.773840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   62.773842] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   62.773845] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[   62.773847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[   62.773850] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000001B8 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[   62.773858] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x8048bb7c
[   62.773861] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[   62.773871] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Starting mac, retry will be triggered anyway
[   62.773996] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD UNKNOWN
[   62.774014]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   62.774040]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   62.774055]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   62.774373] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to configure RX queues: -5
[   62.786924] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: mac start retry 0
[   62.798061] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   62.896407] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[   62.896458] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[   62.896465] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[   62.896474] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10
[   62.898055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 4
[   62.966467] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   62.966574] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   62.966575] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
[   62.966577] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 81.31fc9ae6.0 so-a0-hr-b0-81.ucode
[   62.966578] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[   62.966579] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00A082F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   62.966580] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   62.966581] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D8B5C | branchlink2
[   62.966582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001A30 | interruptlink1
[   62.966583] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00001A30 | interruptlink2
[   62.966583] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00014F1A | data1
[   62.966584] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
[   62.966585] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   62.966585] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   62.966586] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001D861 | tsf low
[   62.966587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   62.966587] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   62.966588] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028FF1 | time gp2
[   62.966589] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   62.966589] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | uCode version major
[   62.966590] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31FC9AE6 | uCode version minor
[   62.966591] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
[   62.966591] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C80002 | board version
[   62.966592] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8032FF00 | hcmd
[   62.966593] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20028000 | isr0
[   62.966593] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   62.966594] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[   62.966595] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[   62.966595] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   62.966596] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   62.966597] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00014F1A | wait_event
[   62.966597] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   62.966598] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   62.966599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   62.966599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   62.966600] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   62.966601] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   62.966601] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000828 | flow_handler
[   62.966648] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   62.966649] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
[   62.966650] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20103428 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   62.966651] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   62.966652] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8046D5A0 | umac branchlink2
[   62.966652] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081500 | umac interruptlink1
[   62.966653] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   62.966654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000033 | umac data1
[   62.966654] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000F | umac data2
[   62.966655] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   62.966656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | umac major
[   62.966656] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31FC9AE6 | umac minor
[   62.966657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028FEC | frame pointer
[   62.966658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886C1C | stack pointer
[   62.966658] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00070C01 | last host cmd
[   62.966659] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   62.966698] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   62.966699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   62.966707] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005081 | IML/ROM data1
[   62.966715] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   62.966720] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   62.966723] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   62.966725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80350002 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   62.966728] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   62.966730] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   62.966733] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   62.966735] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   62.966738] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   62.966740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   62.966743] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   62.966748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   62.966752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   62.966757] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   62.966760] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   62.966762] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[   62.966765] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[   62.966767] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000001B8 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[   62.966775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x8048bb7c
[   62.966778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[   62.966781] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Starting mac, retry will be triggered anyway
[   62.966808] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD UNKNOWN
[   62.966843]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   62.966873]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   62.966898]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   62.967009]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   62.967339] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to configure RX queues: -5
[   62.979033] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: mac start retry 1
[   62.991180] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   63.089387] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[   63.089432] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[   63.089440] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[   63.089448] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10
[   63.090936] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 4
[   63.158951] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   63.159046] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   63.159048] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
[   63.159049] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 81.31fc9ae6.0 so-a0-hr-b0-81.ucode
[   63.159050] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[   63.159051] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00A082F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   63.159052] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   63.159053] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D8B5C | branchlink2
[   63.159054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CEDF6 | interruptlink1
[   63.159055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004CEDF6 | interruptlink2
[   63.159055] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00014F1A | data1
[   63.159056] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
[   63.159057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[   63.159058] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[   63.159058] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001D608 | tsf low
[   63.159059] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   63.159060] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   63.159061] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028D95 | time gp2
[   63.159061] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   63.159062] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | uCode version major
[   63.159063] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31FC9AE6 | uCode version minor
[   63.159064] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
[   63.159065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x18C80002 | board version
[   63.159065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8032FF00 | hcmd
[   63.159066] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20028000 | isr0
[   63.159067] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   63.159067] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[   63.159068] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[   63.159069] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   63.159070] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[   63.159070] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00014F1A | wait_event
[   63.159071] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[   63.159072] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[   63.159073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[   63.159073] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[   63.159074] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   63.159075] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   63.159075] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000828 | flow_handler
[   63.159123] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   63.159123] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
[   63.159124] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20103428 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   63.159125] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   63.159126] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8046D5A0 | umac branchlink2
[   63.159127] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0081500 | umac interruptlink1
[   63.159128] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   63.159128] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000033 | umac data1
[   63.159129] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000F | umac data2
[   63.159130] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   63.159131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000051 | umac major
[   63.159131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x31FC9AE6 | umac minor
[   63.159132] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00028D90 | frame pointer
[   63.159133] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0886C1C | stack pointer
[   63.159133] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00070C01 | last host cmd
[   63.159134] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   63.159172] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[   63.159173] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   63.159181] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000507E | IML/ROM data1
[   63.159189] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   63.159195] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[   63.159197] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   63.159200] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80350002 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   63.159203] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   63.159205] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A482 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   63.159208] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   63.159210] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   63.159213] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   63.159215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   63.159218] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   63.159223] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300504 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   63.159227] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   63.159232] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   63.159235] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00150001 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   63.159237] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[   63.159240] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00350002 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[   63.159242] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000001B8 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[   63.159251] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x8048bb7c
[   63.159253] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[   63.159256] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Starting mac, retry will be triggered anyway
[   63.159320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW error in SYNC CMD UNKNOWN
[   63.159342]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[   63.159373]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[   63.159397]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[   63.159506]  ? __iwl_err+0x18a/0x1a0 [iwlwifi]
[   63.159829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to configure RX queues: -5
[   63.172090] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: mac start retry 2

sudo lshw -c network
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 01
       serial: 70:d8:23:77:a3:9e
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-47-generic firmware=81.31fc9ae6.0 so-a0-hr-b0-81.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:16 memory:6203134000-6203137fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 15
       serial: 04:7c:16:3d:24:37
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.8.0-47-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.0.163 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:52204000-52204fff memory:52200000-52203fff

Distro:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic
Laptop: MSI Cyborg 15 A12V i5 RTX 4060

Full detail of WiFi Diagnostic
https://termbin.com/o0rs

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
